# How to mock static field in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, static, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock a static field in java. This is my code

```
public MyClass{ 
         private static Boolean enabled;
      
         @Value("${enabled:true}")
         public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
             this.enabled = enabled;
         }

         public void getSomething(){
              if(!enabled){
              }
         }
```

When I try to write unit tests, the `if(!enabled)` condition throws null pointer exception. Can you please let me know how to avoid this in mockito

Comment: Why do you want mock instead of using the setter method?

Comment: You can use org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classUnderTest, "field", "value") for setting field into mocked class, but defenately I don't know why do you want to test setter method

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to rewrite your code.

Maybe it is possible for you to initialize `enabled` when the class is created. Also, it will help you to avoid a situation when your class is created but setter hasn't been called yet.

```
private final Boolean enabled; 

public MyClass(@Value("${enabled:true}" Boolean enabled)) { 
this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

In general, it is an anti-pattern to use statics in your code, because it reduces testability. Mockito is useful for mocking non-static stuff. In the end, if you can't rewrite your code to make it more testable, there is always PowerMock for you to help. But, keep in mind, using of PowerMock makes everything worse - tests can't run in parallel for example.

Comment: With Junit5 you can’t use PowerMock.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I use the above snippet, I get syntax error 

',' or ')' expected, 
'=' expected, 
Value expected, 
Identifier expected, 
Type expected, 

at 

public MyClass(@Value("${enabled:true}" Boolean enabled))


.I am using java 15.

Comment: @Ann, yes, I have missplaced ")", it should be after closing double quote.
>> 
    public MyClass(@Value("${enabled:true}") Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }